# How do I get the full list of models available on the NeuroML Database?

Tags: neuroml-database

I would like to get the list of all cell models in the NeuroML-DB.org. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [NeuroML-DB API](https://neuroml-db.org/api), you can get the list of all models in the database in JSON format with the following URL:

[`https://neuroml-db.org/api/models`](https://neuroml-db.org/api)

Which will show JSON like:

[image]

To get the list of all cell models, filter the resulting array by Type="CL"